# How do I get certain attributs from JSON output?

Tags: arrays, json, attributes, expression

I am new to JSON and I am using Power Automate to query the ArcGIS database each day for wildfires in the last 24 hours. Everything works, but I am unsure how to get certain attributes from my Parse JSON action. My JSON output looks like this:

** "attributes": {
"OBJECTID": 324948,
"SourceOID": 28045274,
"ABCDMisc": null,
"ADSPermissionState": "DEFAULT",
"ContainmentDateTime": null,
"ControlDateTime": null,
"CreatedBySystem": "firesponse",
"IncidentSize": 282,
"DiscoveryAcres": 282,
"DispatchCenterID": "TXTIC",
"EstimatedCostToDate": null,
"FinalAcres": null,
"FinalFireReportApprovedByTitle": null,
"FinalFireReportApprovedByUnit": null,
"FinalFireReportApprovedDate": null,
"FireBehaviorGeneral": null,
"FireBehaviorGeneral1": null,
"FireBehaviorGeneral2": null,
"FireBehaviorGeneral3": null,
"FireCause": "Undetermined",
"FireCauseGeneral": null,
"FireCauseSpecific": null,
"FireCode": null,
"FireDepartmentID": null,
"FireDiscoveryDateTime": 1690409269000,
"FireMgmtComplexity": "Type 5 Incident",
"FireOutDateTime": null,
"FireStrategyConfinePercent": null,
"FireStrategyFullSuppPercent": null,
"FireStrategyMonitorPercent": null,
"FireStrategyPointZonePercent": null,
"FSJobCode": null,
"FSOverrideCode": null,
"GACC": "SACC",
"ICS209ReportDateTime": null,
"ICS209ReportForTimePeriodFrom": null,
"ICS209ReportForTimePeriodTo": null,
"ICS209ReportStatus": null,
"IncidentManagementOrganization": null,
"IncidentName": "Live Oak Creek",
"IncidentShortDescription": null,
"IncidentTypeCategory": "WF",
"IncidentTypeKind": "FI",
"InitialLatitude": 28.78373,
"InitialLongitude": -98.76591,
"InitialResponseAcres": null,
"InitialResponseDateTime": null,
"IrwinID": "{A655CB29-B0DA-4C69-A5C5-C99C7ED05C8D}",
"IsFireCauseInvestigated": null,
"IsFireCodeRequested": 0,
"IsFSAssisted": null,
"IsMultiJurisdictional": null,
"IsReimbursable": null,
"IsTrespass": null,
"IsUnifiedCommand": 0,
"LocalIncidentIdentifier": "232655",
"ModifiedBySystem": "firesponse",
"PercentContained": 80,
"PercentPerimeterToBeContained": null,
"POOCity": null,
"POOCounty": "Frio",
"POODispatchCenterID": "TXTIC",
"POOFips": "48163",
"POOJurisdictionalAgency": "State",
"POOJurisdictionalUnit": "TXTXS",
"POOJurisdictionalUnitParentUnit": null,
"POOLandownerCategory": "Private",
"POOLandownerKind": "Private",
"POOLegalDescPrincipalMeridian": null,
"POOLegalDescQtr": null,
"POOLegalDescQtrQtr": null,
"POOLegalDescRange": null,
"POOLegalDescSection": null,
"POOLegalDescTownship": null,
"POOPredictiveServiceAreaID": "SA14",
"POOProtectingAgency": "SFS",
"POOProtectingUnit": "TXTXS",
"POOState": "US-TX",
"PredominantFuelGroup": null,
"PredominantFuelModel": null,
"PrimaryFuelModel": null,
"SecondaryFuelModel": null,
"TotalIncidentPersonnel": null,
"UniqueFireIdentifier": "2023-TXTXS-232655",
"WFDSSDecisionStatus": "No Decision",
"EstimatedFinalCost": null,
"OrganizationalAssessment": null,
"StrategicDecisionPublishDate": null,
"CreatedOnDateTime_dt": 1690415597423,
"ModifiedOnDateTime_dt": 1690487632383,
"IsCpxChild": 0,
"CpxName": null,
"CpxID": null,
"SourceGlobalID": "{602A5D6E-21BD-4F89-AA60-DD9200C6F2E9}",
"GlobalID": "c41dcdc3-8109-4f24-a66d-da9a497eb19e"
},
"geometry": {
"x": -98.823218,
"y": 28.781057
}**

I get this output for each wildfire, so there is a loop in my flow that gets the above data for each wildfire on record. For the State attribute, I have the following code to replace certain values:

**if(equals(items('Apply_to_each_2')?['attributes']?['POOState'], 'US-MI'), 'Michigan'
,'false')**

This replaces the output of US-MI with Michigan. In  my loop, this output will be used to update a SharePoint list. But I don't know how to get the other attributes I need. I need the following values:

**"FireCause"
"ICS209ReportDateTime"
"IncidentName"
"InitialLatitude"
"InitialLongitude"
"POOCity"
"POOCounty"
"POOLandownerCategory"
"POOLandownerKind"**

Do I need to have an expression of some sort to pull out the attributes I want? If so, what would that look like?

Any help would be appreciated. Please remember that I am new and need your answers to be, well...dumbed down...

I haven't tried any codes or expressions yet because I don't know what I'm supposed to do or what it's supposed to look like. I found answers to similar questions, but they are over my head.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the attributes are too "nested" in Power Automate to be readily available. I had to write an expression for each variable I needed to populate.

```
items('Apply_to_each_2')?['attributes']?['FireCause']
```

Problem solved!